# What does AzurePipeline failed mean in eslint

Tags: azure, eslint

Using VS Code ESLint extension, I have a AzurePipelines failed warning. What does this mean?

Comment: Can you please share the error your getting here

Comment: Yes, when I am using Visual Studio Code, and select the icon to see which extensions I have, then select the ESLint extension, there is a text box toward the top of the ESLint page which states: "Azure Pipelines|Failed". I can not find documentation regarding the Azure Pipelines are as respects ESLint loading. Thanks for your time spent on my question!